# Ruby on Rails: using send_data with Ajax call displays ascii instead of image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, image

I'm reading an image in an `link_to_remote` call,and then using `send_data` 
i send the read image as

```
:type => "image/png" :disposition => 
"inline"
```

but when the div tag gets updated i see only ascii characters 
but if i do the same operation using normal call(link_to) i see it 
functioning normal. could someone explain please?

my view:

```
<%= link_to_remote("flip",
     :update => "img",
     :url => {:action => "flip"}
     )%>
<div id="img"></div>
```

controller:

```
def flip
   filename="/public/picture/filename/1/scaler_1.jpg"
    img=File.read(filename)
    ilist = Magick::ImageList.new
    @picture=ilist.from_blob(img)
    @picthumb=@picture.flip!
    @out=@picthumb.to_blob
    send_data(@out,:filename =>'workshopimage', :type => "image/png", 
:disposition => "inline")
end
```

the above doesnt work
but with my view as

```
<%= link_to("flip",
     :action => "flip"
     )%>
```

it works....so doesnt it mean i need to do some thing more incase of an 
ajax call ..am i missing something ..?

Thanks
Shaunak

PS: the question above is copy paste of another post by some other user on some other forum yet unanswered. My problem is exactly same, only i am using gruff graphs. Taken from : http://lists.rubyonrails.org/pipermail/rails/2006-May/041499.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is How i could solve this using the Hint given by robbit:

```
<div id = "graphDiv">

<%= link_to_function("show", " var i = document.createElement('img'); i.src = '" + show_graph_hcfcd_url(1) + "'; $(graphDiv).appendChild(i); ") %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to link_to_remote for this, you'll want to update the image's src attribute to point to the URL:

```
link_to_function "flip", "myImage.src = '" + url_for(:action => "flip") + "'"
```

Comment: when i do this. And view the source it looks like it should work accept, i still dont see them image.  In you answer  does 'myImage' stand for <img id='myImage'/> ?

Answer (score 0):

Robbrit's answer is very useful, but I find the solution to just be ok for Chrome, and a failure under IE8 and Firefox. When I click the link, the image can not be updated. What's your opinion, specifically in IE and Firefox?

I found the solution, still using the method robbrit provided. Using `src=url?+Math.random()` will be ok under IE8 and Firefox.